# get YEAR from datetime format in mysql using codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a `codeigniter` application and I need to get the `year` from a mysql field with `datetime` datatype. I need to do this using CI `active record` using the following way.

```
$this->db->select(YEAR("added_date"));
$this->db->from("news");
$this->db->order_by("added_date", "DESC");
$this->db->where('published', 1);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->get();
```

but I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function YEAR() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/...
```

I use codeigniter 2.1.x (if needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YEAR` is a MYSQL function not codeigniter function:

```
$this->db->select('YEAR(`added_date`)');
```